# line-move-1 in temp buffer, sometimes results in unexpected point

Tags: debugging

I have some code that loads a file into a temp buffer and tries to do some sub-string operations on the temp buffer. But I have noticed that the same code and file sometimes gives different results and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have simplified the code to create a minimal example:

file test.txt:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

so just 10 lines of 'a'.

Then I have some code that goes to a given position, the beginning of the line and then moves one line up with `line-move-1` (using `line-move` shows the same effect):

```
(defun move-around (pos)
  (goto-char pos)
  (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
  (message "above: pos %s point %s" pos (point))
  (line-move-1 -1)
  (message "point now is %s" (point)))
```

And the code that loads the file and calls the function:

```
(defun test-move ()
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents-literally "./test.txt" nil nil nil t)
    (move-around 108)))
```

When I call this with:

```
(test-move)
```

I expected the code to deterministically always return the same result.
However, most of the time, the result is "point now is 89" (which is the result I expect), but sometimes the result is "point now is 91" or "point now is 93"

Example Output in *Messages*:

```
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 89
"point now is 89"
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 93
"point now is 93"
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 93
"point now is 93"
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 93
"point now is 93"
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 89
"point now is 89"
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 89
"point now is 89"
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 89
"point now is 89"
above: pos 108 point 100
point now is 89
"point now is 89"
```

What could be the cause for the same code giving different results?

The point before the call to line-move-1 is at the first character of the last line, so I don't see how it could result in point being 91 or 93 afterwards, which is in the middle of the second to last line, rather than the beginning of that line.

I can only reproduce this when I run the code multiple times by using `eval-last-sexp`, and it seems to matter if I move the cursor around in my code buffer in between invocations of `eval-last-sexp`. When I do

```
    (defun call-often ()
      (dotimes (i 100)
        (test-move)))
```

all 100 times I get the same "89" result.

Any advice on how I can debug further what exactly is happening here? What can influence movements within `with-temp-buffer` while the code is running?

Edit:
I can reproduce this not only on my main machine, but also on my Phone running emacs in Android Termux and my Notebook.

I think the best way I can reproduce it is by doing this:

- put the functions and the invocation into a file so the file looks like:

  ```
    (defun move-around (pos)
      (goto-char pos)
      (goto-char (pos-bol))
      (message "above: pos %s point %s, buffer-size %s" pos (point) (buffer-size))
      (line-move-1 -1)
      (message "point now is %s, buffer-size %s" (point) (buffer-size)))

    (defun test-move ()
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file-contents-literally "./test.txt" nil nil nil t)
        (move-around 108)))

    (test-move)
  ```
- `eval-last-sexp` the functions and then the (test-move)
  It returns 89 as expected
- add a two new lines below, insert three space characters, go a line back up (so cursor is back at the line just below `(test-move)`)
- `eval-last-sexp` now returns 91 quite reliably for me
- It seems like the exact result depends on the number of spaces I entered between invocations.

Comment: I can not reporiduce it here using `eval-last-sexp`. But you can try printing the `(buffer-size)` additionally... see if that is constant.

Comment: Thanks for trying it @dalanicolai! The buffer-size stays constant at 110 in both cases when point is 89 and 91 / 93. I'll try if I can reproduce it in my work machine tomorrow.

Comment: I can reproduce it in two other machines and updated the exact steps I'm doing to reproduce it.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Comment out the calls to `message`, and just do `M-x debug-on-entry RET test-move RET`. Then walk through the debugger with `d` (or `c` to skip through a step). That should show you exactly what's going on.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce it now indeed. Weird indeed. As the comment before the `line-move-1` definition says it is the gut of `previous-line`, I have tried using `previous-line` also, then the behavior is even more weird. Also, I have tried `(forward -1)` in which case the function seems to work correctly. Furthermore, I have used all variants of `move-around` within `test.txt` itself, in which case all variants seem to work fine. I have no idea what happens here (you could file a bug and you might get an answer), but at least using `(forward-line -1)` seems to work correctly.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that I printed out also `(buffer-substring (point) (point-max))` and indeed then we can see that `point` ends up at various places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Dalanicolai and @drew, I think the answer is:

- don't use `move-line-1` but use `(forward-line -1)` instead

What seems to be happening is that line-move-1 calls line-move-finish (https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/simple.el#L8124)
with goal-column derived from variable `temporary-goal-column`. (https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/simple.el#L8005)

I can see that doing the movements before calling `eval-last-sexp` is affecting the value of `temporary-goal-column`, and `line-move-1` then moves to the goal-column.

In summary, I think `move-line-1` is simply not meant to be used in scripts like this.